# ​P​i​ =​= ​3​.​2​

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, calculus

Inspired by [this video of *Infinite Series*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ineO1tIyPfM).

#### Introduction

Pi is defined as the ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a circle. But how is a circle defined? Usually a circle is defined as the points with constant distance to the centerpoint (let us assume that the center is at `(0,0)`). The next question would be: How do we define the *distance*? In the following we are considering different notions of distances (induced by the `Lp`-norms):

Given a norm (=something that measures a *length*) we can easily construct a *distance* (=distance between two points) as follows:

```
dist(A,B) := norm (A-B)
```

The euclidean norm is given by:

```
norm((x,y)) = (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)
```

This is also called the *L2-norm*. The other *Lp-norms* are constructed by replacing the `2` in the above formula by other values between 1 and infinity:

```
norm_p((x,y)) = (|x|^p + |y|^p)^(1/p)
```

The unit circles for those different norms have quite distinct shapes:

[image]

#### Challenge

Given a `p >= 1`, calculate the ratio of circumference to diameter of a *Lp-circle* with respect to the `Lp`-norm with an accuracy of four significant figures.

#### Testcases

We can use that for `p,q` with `1 = 1/p + 1/q` we get the same ratio for the `Lp` as well as the `Lq` norm. Furthermore for `p = q = 2` the ratio is minimal, and for `p = 1, q = infinity` we get a ratio of 4, so the ratios are always between `pi` and `4`.

```
p   or  q            ratio
1       infinity     4
2       2            3.141592
1.623   2.60513      3.200
1.5     3            3.25976
4       1.33333      3.39693
```

Comment: The shapes are known as Lamé curves or superellipses and exist for 0 < _p_ < 1 too, even though the norm itself doesn't (because it violates the triangle inequality). The Wikipedia article for the superellipse includes a closed form for the area.

Comment: @Neil We do however need to consider the circumference, not the area, which - as far as I know - can only be calculated via a arc length integral.

Comment: Sorry, by the time I'd finished reading up on them I'd forgotten what the question had asked for.

Comment: Lovely challenge!

Comment: It's interesting to note that the area formula (`A = πr²`) does not hold for `p ≠ 2`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Haha congrats, this is exactly what the title is an allusion to :D

Comment: the L2 norms sound like things in non-euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 14):

## Python + scipy, 92 bytes

```py
from scipy.integrate import*
lambda p:2/p*quad(lambda x:(x/x**p+(1-x)**(1-p))**(1/p),0,1)[0]
```

Formula is from [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254620/pi-in-arbitrary-metric-spaces).

Comment: When testing an implementation with this appraoch I had trouble with the convergence of that approach, due to the singularity at `x=1`, how does your submission do?

Comment: Scipy is not part of the Python standard library. Maybe switch to Sage?

Comment: @flawr It seems `scipy` handles it fine. All examples are within the required accuracy.

Comment: @busukxuan There is no requirement on PPCG that allows you to only use standard libraries. But I'll mention it in the title anyways.

Comment: +1 for finding the formula. I couldn't, and didn't like to try my own integration because I was afraid of feeling bad when later someone else comes with a closed formula.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I did my own integration to avoid feeling bad for using someone else's closed formula :-P

Comment: @ChristianSievers I actually also included [another formla](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?x%28t%29%20%3A%3D%20%28cos%28t%29%29%5E%7B2/p%7D%20%5Cquad%20y%28t%29%3A%3D%20%28sin%28t%29%29%5E%7B2/p%7D%20%5C%5C%20s%20%3D%20%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi/2%7D%20%5Csqrt%5Bp%5D%7B%28x%27%28t%29%29%5Ep+%28y%27%28t%29%29%5Ep%7D%20dt) in the sandbox, in case you're interested=)

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 31 bytes

```
0:1e-3:1lyG^-lG/^v!d|G^!slG/^sE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29gZZiqa2xlmFPpHqeb464fV6aYUuMep1gMYhe7/v9vqGcKAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S4jwrvhvYGWYqmtsZZhT6R2nm@OtH1emmFLjHadYDGIXu/53CflvyGXEZahnZmQMJE25TAA).

#### Explanation

This generates the *x*,*y* coordinates of one quarter of the unit circle sampled at 1001 points with step 0.001 in *x*. The length of the quarter of circle is approximated by that of the polygonal line that passes through those points; that is, the sum of the lengths of the 1000 segments. Length is of course computed according to `p`-norm. Multiplying the result by 2 gives the approximate lenght of half a circle, that is, pi.

```
0:1e-3:1   % Push [0 0.001 0.002 ... 0.999 1]. These are the x coordinates of
           % the vertices of the polygonal line that will approximate a quarter
           % of the unit circle
l          % Push 1
y          % Duplicate [0 0.001 0.002 ... 0.999 1] onto the top of the stack.
G          % Push input, p
^          % Element-wise power: gives [0^p 0.001^p ... 1^p]
-          % Element-wise subtract from 1: gives [1-0^p 1-0.001^p ... 1-1^p]
lG/        % Push 1, push p, divide: gives 1/p
^          % Element-wise power: gives [(1-0^p)^(1/p) (1-0.001^p)^(1/p) ...
           % ... (1-1^p)^(1/p)]. These are the y coordinates of the vertices
           % of the polygonal line
v          % Concatenate vertically into a 2×1001 matrix. The first row contains
           % the x coordinates and the second row contains the y coordinates
!          % Transpose
d|         % Compute consecutive differences down each column. This gives a
           % 1000×2 matrix with the x and y increments of each segment. These
           % increments will be referred to as Δx, Δy
G          % Push p
^          % Element-wise power
!          % Transpose
s          % Sum of each column. This gives a 1×1000 vector containing
           % (Δx)^p+(Δy)^p for each segment
lG/        % Push 1/p
^          % Element-wise power. This gives a 1×1000 vector containing 
           % ((Δx)^p+(Δy)^p)^(1/p) for each segment, that is, the length of 
           % each segment according to p-norm
s          % Sum the lenghts of all segments. This approximates the length of
           % a quarter of the unit circle
E          % Multiply by 2. This gives the length of half unit circle, that is,
           % pi. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 10):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica), <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

<sup>*3 bytes saved thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/9288).*</sup>
<sup>*1 byte saved thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/81203).*</sup>

```
\!\(2N@∫\_0\%1\@+++(a^-#-1)^(1-#)\%#a\)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P0YxRsPIz@FRx@qYeIMYVcMYB21tbY3EOF1lXUPNOA1DXWXNGFXl93N7EmM01f4HlmamljgEFGXmlUQr69qlOSjHqtUFJyfm1VVzGepwGelwGeqZGRmDKFMdLhOu2v8A) Pure function. Takes a number as input and returns a number as output. The Unicode characters are U+222B for `\[Integral]` and U+F74C for `\[DifferentialD]`.

Comment: `2NIntegrate[(1+(a^-#-1)^(1-#))^(1/#),{a,0,1}]&`

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P0YxRsPIz@FRx@qYeIMYVcMYB21tbY3EOF1lXUPNOA1DXWXNGFXl93N7EmM01f4HlmamljgEFGXmlUQr69qlOSjHqtUFJyfm1VVzGepwGelwGeqZGRmDKFMdLhOu2v8A)

Comment: @att Thanks! It's funny how none of us thought to use the `MakeExpression` syntax for years.

Comment: It's rare in golf that an expression is complicated enough for those forms to save enough bytes to make up for the `\!\( \)` overhead, to be fair.

Comment: `(1-#)` -> `++-#` for another -1

Answer (score 6):

### PARI/GP, <s>48</s> 43 bytes

It's easy after @orlp has found the formula, and @alephalpha's version saves 5 bytes:

```
p->2*intnum(u=0,1,(1+(u^-p-1)^(1-p))^(1/p))
```

To add something slightly useful, let's calculate the `p` for which we get `3.2`:

```
? f=p->2*intnum(u=0,1,(1+(u^-p-1)^(1-p))^(1/p));
? solve(p=1,2,f(p)-3.2)
%2 = 1.623002382384469009676324702
```

#### Correct usage

While the code gives results that are much more exact than the challenge demands, it can easily be improved a lot: if we replace the upper integration limit `1` with `[1,1/p-1]` (giving what the manual calls the singularity exponent) then all shown digits of `f(2)` agree with `Pi`. This is still true if we increase the precision to 100  (type `\p100`).

However, after that change the `solve` computation no longer worked. I changed the inner term to explicitely handle the case `u=0` and also changed to a different computer with a newer PARI version and 64 bit (which implies a higher default precision).

Here is the improved calculation of the `p` value for `Pi=3.2`, and let's also have a look at the real Pi:

```
? f=p->2*intnum(u=0,[1,1/p-1],if(u,(1+(u^-p-1)^(1-p))^(1/p),0));
? f(2)
%2 = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842
? Pi
%3 = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842
? solve(p=1,2,f(p)-3.2)
%4 = 1.6230023823844690096763253745604419761
```

Comment: `p->2*intnum(u=0,1,(1+(u^-p-1)^(1-p))^(1/p))`

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 42 bytes

```
f(p)=2∫_0^1(x/x^p+(1-x)^{1-p})^{1/p}dx/p
```

Port of [orlp's integration formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106036/68261). Yay for integration built-in!

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g5capgcp0h)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 80 bytes

Based on [orlp's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106036/58563). This JS implementation is quite slow. You may want to try `i=1e-7` (or even higher) for a faster approximation.

*Note*: This is basically intended for Chrome and Edge only. An equivalent ES6 version using `Math.pow()` on Firefox 50.1 seems to be *much* slower.

*Edit*: According to Neil, this should also work fine on Firefox 52.

```js
f=
p=>{for(i=5e-8,s=x=0;(x+=i)<1;)s+=i*(x**(1-p)+(1-x)**(1-p))**(1/p);return 2/p*s}

console.log(f(1).toFixed(3))
console.log(f(2).toFixed(3))
console.log(f(1.623).toFixed(3))
```

Comment: The ES7 version seemed pretty sprightly when I tried it using Firefox 52 (I didn't measure it scientifically, but it felt about the same speed as Chrome; Edge froze on me).

Comment: @Neil Thanks for your feedback. Updated accordingly.